# WebView does not really support CORS in JavaFX 2.2?

Tags: jquery, webview, javafx-2, cors

- We implemented app that used WebView of JavaFx for showing webpages and they were deployed at Bob domain.
- In web pages, javascript block had use jquery ajax do GET request to Alice domain.
  Alice domain filtered request by CORS filter like http://software.dzhuvinov.com or eBay.
- And at Alice domain, these CORS filters  also checked Origin header from request.
  If Origin attribute was not in request header that not be a valid CORS request. And browser fire error because doesn't have Access-Control-Allow-Origin attribute in response header
- We used Wireshark to trace request header and detected that browser of WebView did not add Origin attribute. Then we also check the browsers(Firefox, Chrome, IE) and had supported.

So how to make browser of WebView add Origin like others or solution? And we also try to add Origin in headers of jquery ajax setting but browser leave it out.

Thanks

Comment: Review the developer discussion on [CORS in WebView (RT-35868)](https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-35868).

Comment: Thank you so much! Your link helped us

Answer (score 3):

For those who haven't/don't want to sign up to JIRA.

Adding `sun.net.http.allowRestrictedHeaders=true` as a VM arg will turn cors back on for JavaFX WebView.